# Dropbox is slowing Windows explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, dropbox

I've found out that **Dropbox** is really and I mean really **affecting Windows explorer performance**. I'm using Windows Explorer as primary explorer in Windows. Dropbox is adding some extensions to it - **some icons on folders in special Dropbox folder** and also **right click menu**. Fact is that everything is saved on dropbox server and you have to wait till it's downloaded. But last 3 days **Dropbox is overloaded** and I'm experiencing **Server error 500** on their website and application just says synchronizing like whole day. In that case **Windows Explorer** is like you have to **wait a minute** for **directory being fully loaded** - all files, images etc. And also no right click working. After **disabling Dropbox** and **restarting my PC** everything is cool. I've found out that till the Dropbox cannot reach server it is okay but after **Dropbox connection is estabilished** and **Dropbox** will being **overloaded Explorer will just stop working**.

I was just wondering if you guys are experiencing the same problem as me and few of my friends. And I'd like to notify Dropbox developers about it because it really annoying but I have no idea where or how to do so.

Comment: Sounds like DropBox is trying to sync everything. Can you live without the sync feature? Just uninstall the app and use browser-based storage.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well I'm really addicted on those features :/ So I hope they will fix it soon otherwise I'll probably try another cloud solution.

Answer (score 0):

After an update of Dropbox in the background of my Windows 10 PC (64bit), Windows explorer started to freeze for about 20 seconds after creating a new folder. And changing from one folder to another 'took ages'. Both also outside of the Dropbox folder.

After uninstalling Dropbox everything was fine again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's sort of implied that the desired solution involves keeping DropBox.